# URL Rewriting friendly URL with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm interested in rewriting a url which is already "friendly" in order to clean up what is already in the path.

At the moment, I have a URI which points to `http://example.com/page/index/home`, but ideally id like to have the remove page/index completely, and just have `http://example.com/home`.

Comment: What's your current .htaccess?

Comment: At the moment, i'm just stripping out the index.php file (as i'm autoloading classes)

`RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ index.php/$1`

Comment: which framework you are working?

Comment: I made my own lightweight framework, though should have put more thought into creating a routing class.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can just do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/home$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

`QSA` stands for Query String Append. It will append the query string (your GET parameters) to the end of your URL automatically if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/index/home$   /home [L]
```

If you know the specific page you are matching

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^home$   page/index/home [NC]
```